# How can I define a function with a variable with subscript?

Tags: functions, variable, subscript

I want to define a function in Mathematica:

$$h(\tau_x)=\tau_x$$

$\tau_x$ has no special meaning. To be honest, it's totally OK if I use the function $h(x)=x$ to replace $h(\tau_x)=\tau_x$. It doesn't influence the final value I want. I just want to make this function look better.

Here is what I tried

```
In[85]:= h[Subscript[\[Tau], x]_]:=Subscript[\[Tau], x]
In[88]:= h[4]
Out[88]= 1
In[89]:= h[x_]:=x
In[90]:= h[4]
Out[90]= 4
In[91]:= <<Notation`
In[92]:= Symbolize[Subscript[\[Tau], x]]
In[93]:= h[Subscript[\[Tau], x]_]:=Subscript[\[Tau], x]
In[94]:= h[4]
Out[94]= Subscript[\[Tau], x]
```

Here is the image:

[image]

Comment: I recommend you don't try this.

Comment: @lericr hhh, my sanity tells me so, too. 
But our foumulas does look better if such a thing is possible. And it would be more convenient if the variables in Mathematica corresponde to the original math form.

Comment: First, that's a subjective opinion, and one that I disagree with. I find all of the extra semantic-free decorations to be very distracting, less visually pleasing, and not at all convenient. But subjective opinions are subjective opinions.

Comment: Second, Mathematica suffers a bit from its own success. People expect things from it that would be so infeasibe in other languages as to not even come under consideration. Remember, at the end of the day Wolfram Language is a programming language (or a computational language if you prefer). It needs some constraints to be able to parse and compute deterministically. Thus the way pattern matching works for arguments. It has its own sort of elegance, and it's just inappropriate to compare it to free form mathematical notation that can be explained on-the-fly (and needn't even be unambiguous).

Comment: @lericr
Thanks! I got your idea and I won't waste more time on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though this is – as already mentioned by @lericr in the comments and many times across this SE – generally not advised, I still want you to explain why your code does not work.

After symbolizing `Subscript[τ, x]` and defining `h`, take a look at the `InputForm` (!) of downvalues assigned to `h`:

```
Clear[h];
h[Subscript[τ, x] _] := Subscript[τ, x]
DownValues[h] // InputForm
(* {HoldPattern[h[τ⎵Subscript⎵x*_]] :> τ⎵Subscript⎵x} *)
```

Do you see the problem? `Subscript[τ, x] _` got parsed as `Subscript[τ, x]*_` – multiplication between `Subscript[τ, x]` and "something". That is why the following code returns a somehow "unexpected" result:

```
h[2 Subscript[τ, x]]
(* Subscript[τ, x] *)
```

Therefore, you need to force the parser to understand `Subscript[τ, x]_` as `Pattern[τ, Blank[]]`. The cleanest way to do this is by using a colon:

```
Clear[h];
h[Subscript[τ, x] : _] := Subscript[τ, x]
h[4]
(* 4 *)
```

Comment: Thank you!
But where is the semicolon you mentioned?

There is only colon in 
`h[Subscript[τ, x] : _] := Subscript[τ, x]`.

And there is error when I run it:
`Syntax::sntxf: "h[" cannot be followed by "Subscript[\[Tau],x]:_]".`
Is there any error?

Sorry if I misunderstood you, I'm a big noob for Mathematica.

Comment: Could you show your complete code if convenient? I think I can figure out where I made a mistake by checking your code.

Comment: @XiangyuCui, ah, I meant _colon_ instead of _semicolon_, sorry for the confusion. Note that you still have to first symbolize your variable, your code should look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/na6wt.png).

Comment: Sure, thank you!